# How to wait for khttp (kotlin) response in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, http, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I've been trying to use khttp to send an .jpg file in an android activity but haven't been able to make it work.

```
fun sendImage(view: View) {

    try {
        var bmp = (imageView?.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
        var bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, bos)
        var response: Response? = null
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.image_desc).text = "Connecting to " + SERVER_URL;

        try {
            val job=GlobalScope.launch {
                response = post(SERVER_URL, files = listOf(File(path).fileLike(name = "Image.jpg")))
            }

            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.image_desc).text = "Image contains: ${response?.text}"
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.image_desc).text = "Connection failed - please check fields are valid"
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.image_desc).text = e.toString()
        }

    } catch (e: UnknownHostException) {
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.image_desc).text = "Unknown host :("
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.image_desc).text = "IO exceptiion :("
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.image_desc).text = "Other exception :("
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

As soon as i send the image, image_desc textView's text change to Image contains: null. I'm sure the server isn't the problem, since when I test it with this python code:

```
import requests

url=...
files = {'file': open('./test/cat.jpg', 'rb')}
r=requests.post(url,files=files)
print (r.text)
```

I get the desired response after a short delay. I've tried turning sendImage to a suspend func and writing job.join() but that crashes the app. How should  fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try next code:

```
val job = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    val postOperation = async(Dispatchers.IO) { // <- extension on launch scope, launched in IO dispatcher
        // blocking I/O operation
        post(SERVER_URL, files = listOf(File(path).fileLike(name = "Image.jpg")))
    }
    response = postOperation.await() // wait for result of I/O operation without blocking the main thread
    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.image_desc).text = "Image contains: ${response?.text}"
}
```

Also add next line to app's `build.gradle` dependency:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'
```

**Note** that `GlobalScope` is discouraged to use, to launch a coroutine use an instance of `CoroutineScope`, or existing instance like [`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope) or [`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope).

---

**UPDATE**:

The correct approach would be to use [`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) in `Activity`:

```
lifecycleScope.launch { // uses Dispatchers.Main context
    val response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { // change context to background thread
        // blocking I/O operation
        post(SERVER_URL, files = listOf(File(path).fileLike(name = "Image.jpg")))
    }
    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.image_desc).text = "Image contains: ${response?.text}"
}
```

Comment: Now it waits for a response, however it doesn't send the file. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: maybe your `post` method works incorrectly, or file doesn't exists. Did it work before?

Comment: I ran the whole app on a test server in my local network and it did work. Since then I deployed the server on a cloud and it hasn't been working since.

Comment: do you see some errors in the logs when you are sending file? Is `response` being initialized? what do you see in `image_desc` TextView

Comment: No matter, I mistakenly uploaded old server code. Thank you anyway for you help with coroutines!